# How to random seed from memory usage?

Tags: c, windows, random

In windows, I want to generate random number with seed: time + memory usage.
I want to get the memory usage from physical memory sytem cache the one that appears in taskmgr.

So, How to get physical memory system cache in c (windows and not .net )?
The random seed may end up something like this:

`srand((unsigned int)(time(0)+ memSystemCache) );`

This is probably get the memory usage from compile-time , it's ok for me.
Is it possible?

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using Win32 I would recommend [CryptGenRandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom) over srand/rand.